# Is there a way to "parse" out the parts of an html with Play for Java?

Tags: java, testing, playframework-2.0

I'm currently testing page renders using play:

```
@Test
    public void renderUpdateUserPage() {
        Content html = update_user.render("Update User");
        assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
        String htmlAsString = contentAsString(html);
        assertThat(htmlAsString).contains("Update User");
        assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"First Name\" class=\"input-large\" id=\"firstName\" name=\"firstName\">");
        assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Last Name\" class=\"input-large\" id=\"lastName\" name=\"lastName\">");
        assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Email Address\" class=\"input-large\" id=\"email\" name=\"email\">");
    }
```

As you can see in the code, I am just copying the html into the `contains()`. What is a better way I can test page content?

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach may be a bit brittle, since even small layout changes will cause your tests to fail. Rather than testing for a specific DOM structure to be there, I'd try to test the behaviour of the page, like submitting the form, and seeing what happens. There's a [blog post about integrating Cucumber and Play](http://www.sebnozzi.com/82/cucumber-and-play/), you could take this as a starting point to test form submission with Cucumber and Fluentlenium.